# Disavow subdomains no longer in use without using webmaster tools

Tags: subdomain, disavow-links

Back in the day I had several subdomains to the same domain to my site in an effort to boost performance SEO-wise. Now when I look back, it seems that putting everything in one domain results in faster performance which is even better for SEO.

What I have done months ago is removed all my subdomains from all webmaster tool accounts registered to my name and I also removed relevant verification files from my server document root folder for each subdomain.

I checked my logs recently and notice that requests are coming in to one of the subdomains.

I think there's a disavow tool in GSC (google search console) but is there a way I can use something like that on subdomains without having to re-register each of them into GSC again? and is there a similar procedure I can follow in yandex and bing (without re-registering my subdomains)?

When this process is done, I want it where in the future, no search engine will ever make a URL request containing any of the subdomains I asked to be removed.

Comment: The clearest, fastest, and safest thing to do is the traditional thing to do. Remove the sub-domains from your DNS and forget about it. Cheers!!

Comment: Maybe I should just do that tonight and see what happens. I just hope google doesn't whine at me if I take this advice.

Comment: You listen to whiners? I don't. Removing the sub-domains is final. If you don't need them, just full the frickin' band-aid off already. If you have a reason to keep them, then keep them. But God sake, don't leave trash about the place. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

> I want it where in the future, no search engine will ever make a URL request containing any of the subdomains

This would seem to be a fruitless task. If a subdomain (or any URL for that matter) has previously been indexed, and particularly if it is still linked to, then it's quite probable that the search engines will continue to have at least the occasional sniff... forever.

The best you can do is to simply make sure the subdomain doesn't resolve, or that it returns a 410 Gone (or block with robots.txt), if you have some kind of wildcard "catch-all" subdomain configuration.

> I think there's a disavow tool in GSC

The "disavow" tool is for *disavowing* incoming links to your site, so they aren't counted when determining your ranking. It has nothing to do with blocking crawling/indexing.

There is a URL removal tool, but this is *simply* for removing your URLs from the search results - it doesn't necessarily influence crawling.